# Set line items in custom sublist

Tags: javascript, netsuite, sublist

A lot of tutorials or reference on how to deal with netsuite sublist but none of them fits what I needed.

I just need to update/add the custom sublist I created in suitelet through client script. This is my suitelet code

```
    //this is a custom sublist
    var sublist = form.addSubList('targetlist', 'list', null, 'target_list');
    sublist.addField('industry', 'text', 'Industry');
    sublist.addField('inp_name', 'text', 'Name');
```

And in client script I just want to add some line items when some field change like

```
function targetListClient(type, name, lineNum) {
    if(name == 'industry') { 
          nlapiSelectNewLineItem('targetlist');
          nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('targetlist', 'industry', 'test');
          nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('targetlist', 'inp_name', 'test again');
          nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('targetlist', 'jobtitle', 'another test');
          nlapiCommitLineItem('targetlist');
    }

}
```

I think this should work but I got this error. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checkvalid' of undefined`

I also try to just set the line item `nlapiSetLineItemValue('industry', 1, 'again')` instead of selecting the current line item but this also is not working.

Am I implementing the sublist concept incorrect? Can someone guide me on this. Thanks.

Comment: I believe your concept is correct, but I don't see anywhere in your code where `checkvalid` is being referenced. Seems that that would be the code you'd want to post as well so we could see why that was `undefined`

Comment: I also noticed that. But I think `checkvalid` was part of netsuite api because whenever I click the link error on the debugger, it gives me this minified code which I think it runs whenever you call these `nlapi` or something....

Comment: I think this is not about the error, is anyone has the idea on how to add line items on the custom sublist created in suitelet via client?

Comment: How is `targetListClient` called? More context on how your code is being used would be helpful. Also, your example call to `nlapiSetLineItemValue` is not correct; it should be `nlapiSetLineItemValue(listName, fieldName, lineIndex, fieldValue);`

Answer (score 1):

**Try using this:**

```
nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('targetlist', 'industry', 'test',false,true);
```

**Explanation:**
nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue has firefieldchanged argument which is set to true by default if you don't set it to false fieldChanged script is called repeatedly causing infinte loop .So try setting it to false .This should solve the problem

Comment: Thank you, your code works on my end. 
I added this on the column/field where I have text and currency as datatype

Answer (score 0):

In function targetListClient, you give a value for field jobtitle, but the sublist creation code only has fields industry and inp_name.

Answer (score 0):

Does your code also have the form.setScript?  You mentioned a client side script.  You need to attach the client side script to your suitelet using form.setScript.

Comment: Yah, I did on my suitelet. But thats not an issue. The client script works perfectly so it was successfully attached on the suitelet. Any ideas on the real question

Answer (score 0):

change the "LIST" to "INLINEEDITOR" and it will work 100%